# showing divs at random and then moving them down in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

guys what i want to make is the div appears at random first and then making them falling down ... here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#test').animate({top: 80 + '%'},900);
});
```

```html
<div id="test" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: You didn't set an initial `top` value, and you'll need a parent element with a certain size to move someting 80% from the top relative to the parent etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.settimeout to call a function that creates your div after a random interval, then have the function call call itself again after it is finished.

html:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
.droper{
    background:#98bf21;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

jquery

```
var ranInterval = 1000 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 4000) + 1);
window.setTimeout( CreateDiv, ranInterval ); 

function CreateDiv()
{
    var ranLeft = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);
    var ranInterval = 1000 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 4000) + 1);
    jQuery('<div class="droper" />').css({top: 0, left: ranLeft }).animate({top: "+=400px"}, 900 ).appendTo('#container' );

    window.setTimeout( CreateDiv, ranInterval );
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the code.
http://jsfiddle.net/chrustlesstulip/b8qo56j5/